# How can BOOST_PP_SEQ_PUSH_BACK create a macro sequence with multiple calls

Tags: c++, boost

### Preamble

What i want to achieve automatically generating a type to enum map from a sequence in boost. AKA, i want to define:

```
#define SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_MAP \
   (BATTERY_STATE, int) \
   (ACCELERATION, float)
```

And generate something like:

```
enum class Subscription {

    BATTERY_STATE,
    ACCELERATION,

};

template <Subscription subsciption> struct type_map;
template <> struct type_map<Subscription::BATTERY_STATE> {
    using type = int;
};
template <> struct type_map<Subscription::ACCELERATION> {
    using type = float;
};
```

Now this can be achieved with some *BOOST_PP* code:

```
#define SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_MAP \
   (BATTERY_STATE, int) \
   (ACCELERATION, float)

enum class Subscription
{
#define LIST_OUT_MAP_ELEMENTS_0(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, elem),

    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(
        LIST_OUT_MAP_ELEMENTS_0, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_MAP)
    )

#undef LIST_OUT_MAP_ELEMENTS_0
};

template <Subscription subsciption>
struct type_map;

#define SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE(subscription_enum_, type_)\
    template<>                                      \
    struct type_map<Subscription::subscription_enum_>             \
    {                                               \
        using type                     = type_;     \
    };                                              \



#define CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE(r, data, i, elem) \
    SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE(                             \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, elem),              \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1, elem)               \
    )

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(
    CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_MAP)
)
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7b5vhPdfo) - check the preprocessor output.

But now i want to add some comments to the Type map:

```
/**
* @brief the battery subscription
*
* Some important notes
* ...
*/
SUBSCRIPTION(BATTERY_STATE, int)

/**
* @brief the acceleration subscription
*
* Some important notes
* ...
*/
SUBSCRIPTION(ACCELERATION, float)

...
```

This would conceptually use [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_PUSH_BACK`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to push these sequence entries onto the macro. However, the preprocessor just doesn't work this way.

### QUESTION

I feel like i could solve this if i could solve the simplified question:

**How can I generate a BOOST_PP sequence from separate macro invocations across the code?**